# CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe memory leak

Tags: cefsharp

CefSharp version 75.1.143.0 memory of CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe is growing rapid far to 1GB.
Angular components are destroyed and removed from the DOM but the memory of CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
keep growing.
Any idea?

Comment: Version 75 is old and unsupported,  it's quite likely there was a memory leak in the particular chromium version that CefSharp is based on. How does version 85 behave?

Comment: We tried 85. Same behavior.

Comment: How does the CEF Sample application behave?  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef are you doing anything more than just loading your webpage in the browser?